# numpy: read in data file and replace keywords

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to read in a data file with the following content

```
1 key1 3
4 5 key2
7 8 9
```

and save it into an array or list.
The keywords `key1` and `key2` should be replaced by `2` and `6`, i.e. the final array should be

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Is there simple solution with e.g. `numpy.genfromtxt` or something similar?

Comment: You might be able to do with a `converter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is not that tricky to do just with plain Python:

```
keys = {'key1': 2, 'key2': 6}
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:  # Assuming data in 'in.txt'
    arr = [[int(elm) if elm.isnumeric() else keys[elm] for elm in line.split()] for line in f]
```